# Is obd code P0133 anything to worry about?

Tags: obd-ii, o2-sensor, p0133

The day before I got this obd code I changed clutch and gear box oil. 15 minutes before I got this code one of my brakes pads completely wore out.  I read a bit about the code and I guess they are not related but I am still learning so please let me know if they could be related.

As for the code, other than for the environment, is it something serious or something I need to worry about, can I just clear and continue to drive?  I plan to sell after a 1-3 months so if nobody notices should be ok.

I suppose if I get some symptoms such as low gas mileage, misfiring or loss of power, only then should I do something?

Is this an easy diy repair, what is the difficulty of diagnosing and fixing this task, might i be better off going to a mechanic?

Can you give me some directions or are there any resources to show me how to diagnose the problem so I know what needs to be done.

Thanks

Comment: That codes means one of the O2 sensors is dying and needs replaced, yes take it to a qualified mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing an O2 sensor ***can*** be a fairly easy DIY replacement. I haven't seen all cars, but on Honda Civics it is fairly simple.

Get the appropriate O2 sensor(s), borrow an O2 sensor socket (auto parts stores in the western US lend tools, YMMV).

Raise the car and secure it with jack stands, climb under the car with your socket, your sensor, your socket handle and possibly some penetrating oil.

Unplug the sensor, remove and replace.

If you consider yourself somewhat experienced with auto mechanics, in particular you know how to SAFELY raise a car, it shouldn't be too much of a challenge. This is not a difficult or complex task and the special tool should be readily available (depending on where you are physically located).

If you are not familiar with or comfortable raising a car safely take it to a mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with @Moab here ... to be more accurate, the code is for the Bank 1 Sensor 1, which means it's the main O2 which adjusts the fuel trims for proper fueling. If this vehicle only has one pre-cat O2 sensor, that makes things easier, as it should be easy to find. If it has two (usually on a V engine), it will be on the same side as the #1 cylinder (in most cases).

You could possibly clear the code and will be okay for a little while. As soon as the OBDII system gets through its drive cycle, the code will most likely come back. Even if it doesn't come back, you'll still be suffering from decreased fuel mileage with the possibility of ruining your catalytic converter in the process.

Even if you are getting rid of the car in a couple of months, please realize most states here in the US have laws which protect the buyer from "undisclosed problems" ... if you know of a problem and don't disclose it during the sale, even if the sale is considered sold "as-is", you can still be found liable for getting it fixed. IOW: Get it changed. You'll probably make it up in improved gas mileage anyways. More than likely, fuel mileage has been decreasing slowly without you really noticing it.

Answer (score 1):

In plainspeak, P0133 means that the O2 sensor is not able to react quickly enough to changes in air-fuel ratio. This can result in the following behavior:

- sluggish throttle response
- poor fuel economy, especially during frequent acceleration/deceleration